# Couting value in list inside of a list

Tags: python, for-loop, count

I want to count identical values in my lists in list.

already I coded it:

```
id_list = [['cat','animal'],['snake','animal'], ['rose','flower'], ['tomato','vegetable']]

duplicates = []
for x in range(len(id_list)):
    if id_list.count(id_list[x][1]) >= 2:
        duplicates.append(id_list[x][1])
print(duplicates)
```

I think it don't work becouse the count is counting id[x][1] and don't seen any other values in rest of lists.
If there any way to count my lists instead of value of that list but leaning on this value?

Thank for all help and advice
Have a nice day!

Comment: Could you attach an expected output of your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the count of all the elements from your list in a dictionary like this:

```
>>> id_list = [['cat','animal'],['snake','animal'], ['rose','flower'], ['tomato','vegetable']]
>>> {k: sum(id_list, []).count(k) for k in sum(id_list, [])}
{'cat': 1, 'animal': 2, 'snake': 1, 'rose': 1, 'flower': 1, 'tomato': 1, 'vegetable': 1}
```

You can extract the elements whose value (count) is greater than 1 to identify as duplicates.

Explanation: `sum(id_list, [])` basically flattens a list of lists, this would work for any number of elements inside your inner lists. `sum(id_list, []).count(k)` stores the count of every `k` inside this flattened list and stores it in a dictionary with `k` as key and the `count` as value. You can iterate this dictionary now and select only those elements whose count is greater than, let’s say 1:

```
my_dict = {k: sum(id_list, []).count(k) for k in sum(id_list, [])}
for key, count in my_dict.items():
    if count > 1:
        print(key)
```

or create the dictionary directly by:

```
flat_list = sum(id_list, [])
>>> {k: flat_list.count(k) for k in flat_list if flat_list.count(k) > 1}
{'animal': 2}
```

Comment: Hello, this is a very nice solution, but could you explain it a little bit? and tell how to put into dictionary only those keys, which are counted more than one? and case if I have 3 or more list elements

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
id_list = [['cat','animal'],['snake','animal'], ['rose','flower'], ['tomato','vegetable']]
els = [el[1] for el in id_list]
[k for k,v in {i:els.count(i) for i in els }.items() if v > 1]

['animal']
```

Kr